# Formulário javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um formulário e nele transformei o valores digitados em objetos para salvar em um cookie, mas não estou conseguindo pegar a partir do segundo valor desse objeto, gostaria de pegar todos os valores, segue o código, já tentei colocar só o código do recruta mas mesmo assim ele da underfined. Se puderem me dá um help

```
<div class="form-prospects">
            <a class="add-prospects" href="#">Adicionar Prospects</a>
        </div>

function Action_InternalFunctions() {
var formProspectsObject = $(containerClass+' .form-prospects');
        if (formProspectsObject.length) {
            Setup_FormProspects(formProspectsObject);
        }
}

var formValuesProspect = {
            prospect: [
                {consultor:'',
                recruta:'',
                venda:''}
            ]
        };
function Setup_FormProspects(formProspectsObject) {
        $.each(formValuesProspect, function(index, value) {
            console.log(index+' '+value);
        });
        formProspectsObject.each(function(i, val) {
            var thisProspectObject = $(this);
            var thisGoto = $(this).find('.goto');
            thisGoto.css('display','none');
            //Gera  =====
            //var countProspect = 0;
            var countProspect2= 0;
            $.each(formValuesProspect['prospect'], function(index, value) {
                console.log(index+' '+value);
                thisProspectObject.prepend('<p class="consult consult-'+index+'">Consultor: <input type="text" placeholder="Consultor" name="consultor" data-consult="'+index+'" id="consultor'+index+'" class="consultor consultor-'+index+'"></p>'+
                    '<p class="recruit recruit-'+index+'">Número de recrutas: <input type="text" placeholder="Quantidade de recrutas" name="recruta" data-recruit="'+index+'" id="recruta'+index+'" class="recruta recruta-'+index+'"></p>'+
                    '<p class="buy buy-'+index+'">Volume de Vendas: <input type="text" placeholder="Volume de Vendas" name="venda" data-buy="'+index+'" id="venda'+index+'" class="venda venda-'+index+'"></p>');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //$('.consultor-'+index).val(value['consultor']);
                    $('.recruta-'+index).val(value['recruta']);
                    $('.venda-'+index).val(value['venda']);
                }, 0.1);    
                //watchProspects($('.consultor-'+index));
                watchProspects2($('.recruit-'+index));
                //countProspect = index;
                countProspect2 = index;
                if(formValuesProspect['prospect'].length-1==index){
                    thisProspectObject.find('.add-prospects').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        //var ddl = thisProspectObject.find('.consult-'+countProspect);
                        var ddl2 = thisProspectObject.find('.recruit-'+countProspect);
                        //var oldcountProspect = countProspect;
                        var oldcountProspect2 = countProspect2;
                        //countProspect = countProspect+1;
                        countProspect2 = countProspect2+1;
                        console.log(countProspect2);
                        //ddl.before('<p class="consult consult-'+countProspect+'"></p>');
                        ddl.before('<p class="recruit recruit-'+countProspect+'"></p>');
                        //ddlHTML = ddl.html().split(oldcountProspect).join(countProspect);
                        ddlHTML2 = ddl2.html().split(oldcountProspect2).join(countProspect2);
                        //$('.consult-'+countProspect).html(ddlHTML);
                        $('.recruit-'+countProspect2).html(ddlHTML2);
                        //watchProspects($('.consultor-'+countProspect));
                        watchProspects2($('.recruit-'+countProspect));

                });
            }
        });
    });
}

// function watchProspects(element){
//  var thisInput = element;
//  thisInput.val(formValuesProspect[thisInput.attr('name')]);
//  thisInput.keyup(function() {
//      if(formValuesProspect['prospect'][Number(thisInput.data('consult'))]!={}){
//          formValuesProspect['prospect'][Number(thisInput.data('consult'))] = {};
//          console.log(thisInput.data('consult'));
//      }
//      formValuesProspect['prospect'][Number(thisInput.data('consult'))][thisInput.attr('name')] = thisInput.val();
//  });
// }

function watchProspects2(element){
    var thisInput = element;
    thisInput.val(formValuesProspect[thisInput.attr('name')]);
    thisInput.keyup(function() {
        if(formValuesProspect['prospect'][Number(thisInput.data('recruit'))]!={}){
            formValuesProspect['prospect'][Number(thisInput.data('recruit'))] = {};
            console.log(thisInput.data('recruit'));
        }
        formValuesProspect['prospect'][Number(thisInput.data('recruit'))][thisInput.attr('name')] = thisInput.val();
    });
}
```